# How to load a custom config file automatically in Codeigniter v4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

I have created a custom config file in the Config folder. **Config/Elearning_config.php**. Now I want to load this using **Autoload.php** of Codeigniter v4. How to do this?

```
<?php namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Elearning_config extends BaseConfig
{
    public $theme = 'theme/etreeks/';

}
```

Comment: like this you can load $Elearning_config = new \Config\Elearning_config(); and use the variable like "$variable = $Elearning_config ->theme;"

Comment: I want to load this automatically. I mean, I want to use **Config/Autoload.php** here. Can you please explain this?

Comment: I have been added the answer check it.

Comment: Autoload loads the classpaths and has nothing to do with loading constants (as i can discern from your comments on the answer). If you want to define constants than define them in constants file like this :  "defined('VARIABLE')      || define('VARIABLE', 'value');". Then you can simply echo VARIABLE anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to load this config file using **Autoload.php**. But a process I have found to load this automatically.

In **BaseController** write his line

```
$this->Elearning_config = new \Config\Elearning_config();
```

And to get from controller

```
echo $this->Elearning_config->theme;
```

I think this is not the correct process to autoload this. But this is working

Comment: But I am not able to get this from view. echo $this->Elearning_config->theme; is not working from view.

Answer (score 0):

All files are loaded inside Config folder by psr4 check line no 3rd value of $psr4 array

```
    $psr4 = [
        'App'         => APPPATH,                // To ensure filters, etc still found,
        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH,                // For custom namespace
        'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',     // check this line if not loaded
    ];
```

It will autoload your configuration 
Now use this file and variable on any controller like below

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
class Home extends BaseController
{
public function index()
{
    $Elearning_config = new \Config\Elearning_config();
    echo $Elearning_config->theme;//  exit;
    return view('welcome_message');
}
}
```

Comment if you have any doubt

Comment: Autoload is not working. Without autoload, the second method is working fine.

Comment: Great then, that means your class is already loaded with $psr4 check above in Autoload.php "'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config'," for more information https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/concepts/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload

Comment: print_r($this->classmap); is also not working from controller

Comment: My question is autoload is not working, so how to do that?. The manual load is working. Your method is manual method. And this is working fine. but auto load is not working yet. $Elearning_config = new \Config\Elearning_config(); means create an object to load. I want to load this automatically. In CI3 $autoload['config'] = array('Elearning_config'); means this will load automatically. no need to make any object. But thanks for your help

Comment: scope remain in Autoload.php or its child class if inherited not in controller but leave it. I had write it down for understanding purpose only. check updated answer.

Comment: Means without **$Elearning_config = new \Config\Elearning_config();** this line this will not work? Isn't possible to load this line automatically?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can reduce the steps using base controller set config value and use it in child class like in base controller "function __construct() {
  $this->elearning_config = new \Config\Elearning_config();
 }"